# How to fetch numbers from a character vectors in R?

Tags: r

I have a character vector and want to fetch a numbers from it both integer as well as Floats.

```
    a <- c("Sam is 5 years old", "Ram is 3.7 years old" , "John is 17 years 2 months old")
```

output should be:

```
      [1]  5  3.7 17.2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `parse_number` from `readr`

```
readr::parse_number(a)
#[1]  5.0  3.7 17.0
```

#### Update

Based on the OP's new example

```
library(stringr)
sapply(str_extract_all(a, "[0-9]+\\s+(years|months)"), function(x) {
       x1 <- readr::parse_number(x)
       head(if(length(x1)==2)   x1 + round(x1[2]/12, 1) else x1, 1)})
#[1]  5.0  7.0 17.2
```

If we don't need to be concerned about dividing by 12 for the 'months, another option is

```
as.numeric(sapply(regmatches(a, gregexpr('[0-9]+', a)), paste, collapse="."))
#[1]  5.0  3.7 17.2
```

Comment: made some changes to code. I want months converted into floating point in output which is not possible with parse_number.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar  Suppose, if your months is 1 year 9 months, what will be output

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar  I updated the post.  Please check if that is what you wanted

Answer (score 3):

Here is a one liner,

```
as.numeric(gsub(' ', '.', trimws(gsub('\\D+', ' ', a))))
#[1]  5.0  3.7 17.2
```